# Enum in Jmeter scripting

Tags: jmeter

Does the JSR223 Sampler or any support enum declarations?
I get an error of,

```
`Encountered "enum" at line 12, column 1.
```

I have enums with default values set in it like,
enum Days {
MONDAY(1),
TUESDAY(2),..
}

[image: JSR223 Sampler]

I get the error in the first line here.

Comment: can you show your script and element configuration ? thx

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I have added an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSR223 Sampler "supports" anything you will type into the "Script" area, the error you're getting is due to [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) underlying language doesn't support `enum` keyword.

If are limited to using Beanshell make sure your code is [Java 1.4 compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4), i.e.

- no enums
- no generics
- no foreach
- etc.

If you need to use enums consider switching to [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, it supports all modern Java features and adds some new on top of them. Moreover, well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled into bytecode so given high and sustained load you will get better performance with Groovy. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more information and scripting best practices.